# how to find index of array item into the array variable

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have array like this

```
let arr1 = [[1,2],[5,6,7], ...[other arr]]
```

and for example I want to find this array `[1,2]` into `arr1`...
so how do that?

And if possible how can delete it in `arr1`

this array `[1,2]` may be in the middle of in `arr1`

I hope it is clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

,is it what you are looking for ?

```js
let arr1          = [[9,0],[9,8],[1,2],[5,6,7],[14,2],[1,3]]

let SearchElement = JSON.stringify([1,2])  // make a JSON of your search

let elmIndex      = arr1.findIndex(x=>JSON.stringify(x)===SearchElement)

console.log( 'findIndex is', elmIndex )

if (elmIndex != -1)        // if found...
  arr1.splice(elmIndex,1)  // remove it from arr1

console.log( arr1 )
```

Comment: That's what I want tnx 
How did it come to your mind convert to json?

Comment: @hamedhatami it's years of coding : experience

Answer (score 0):

This is the very basics of arrays in javascript you should try to look it up first, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

```
console.log(arr1[0]) // outputs [1,2]
arr1 = arr1.shift()
console.log(arr1) // outputs [[5,6,7]]
```